# Does SimpleInjector have the ability to assign a priority order when using RegisterManyForOpenGeneric/GetAllInstances

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am using SimpleInjector as my IoC Container. I have created a Publish/Subscribe framework for which I now need to be able to refine by enabling subscribers to indicate their priority for execution. For example I could create a subscriber for preloading all of the data required for the remainder of a transaction.

One method I can think of is to create a `[SubscriberPriority]` attribute to indicate the requirement during the registration process `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` but I haven't delved any deeper as yet.

Is there a way to manage the order that `GetAllInstances` returns registrations?

Update:

Another option I've just thought of would be to use CoC (Convention over Configuration) to order the instances as they are returned by `GetAllInstances`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're indicating that you are using `GetAllInstances`, I suspect that you use an `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` overload that takes a callback delegate, as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ISubstriber<>),
    (type, impls) => container.RegisterAll(type, impls),
    typeof(ISubstriber<>).Assembly);
```

In that case the order of which the list of implementations is supplied to the delegate depends on the order in which they are returned from the .NET metadata. `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` simply calls `GetExportedTypes()` on the supplied assembly. The order in which these types are returned is highly unreliable and might in a future version of C# even change by recompiling the code and in a future version of the CLR just by restarting the application.

So if the implementations must be placed in the list in a certain order, all you have to to is to order the list of implementations:

```cs
(serviceType, impls) => container.RegisterAll(serviceType,
    impls.OrderBy(type => [some condition]));
```

However, in general I would say that the order of things should not matter. If they do matter, take a good look at your design. There might be some issues here. For instance, the fact that you want to mark some classes with the `[SubscriberPriority]` attribute, indicates that you might be missing an abstraction. Perhaps you should give them their own interface and register them seperately.

Another thing that I would always advice to do is to hide the list of registrations from the application by placing them behind an composite:

```cs
public class CompositeSubscriber<T> : ISubscriber<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<ISubscriber<T>> subscribers;

    public CompositeSubscriber(
        IEnumerable<ISubstriber<T>> subscribers)
    {
        this.subscribers = subscribers;
    }

    public void Handle(T value)
    {
        foreach (var subscriber in this.subscribers)
        {
            subscriber.Handle(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This composite can be registered as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(ISubscriber<>),
    typeof(CompositeSubscriber<>);
```

This case the application can simply depend on `ISubscriber<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<ISubscriber<T>>`. Instead of controlling the order using the callback of the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` method, now you can use the composite to control the order as well.

Comment: I have a composite wrapper for calling the subscribers but agree that event priority is not a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: Having given this more thought the answer is (of course) ... decorators. ;-)